# Designing icons for android

Tags: android, icons

I did some research and found that there 6 different sizes required by Android to display images properly on all sorts of devices.

```
LDPI - 0.75x
MDPI - Original size
HDPI - 1.5x
XHDPI - 2.0x
XXHDPI - 3x
XXXHDPI - 4.0x
```

So suppose I have  100x100 image as a baseline (MDPI), then ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi will be as follows.

```
LDPI - 75x75
HDPI - 150x150
XHDPI - 200x200
XXHDPI - 300x300
XXXHDPI - 400x400
```

But I have confusion as to what should be the `baseline(mdpi)`. How do I select my baseline, does it have to be based on something? I can have different images in my app example a back arrow, home arrow, a background image(full screen), an Add icon and so on. But all these icons have to different sizes. So how can I choose my baseline size?

Answer (score 0):

No need to choose, the mdpi(baseline) density means that one dp is roughly equal to one pixel. So we call it the baseline density.

If we provide icon with size by the definition. We will get all the icon image have same physical size on different density screen(ldpi,mdpi,xdpi and so on) with proper quality.

About the background image, I would recommend to put the background image to `drawable-nodpi` which the image just fill entire screen no matter the density, so just put it there to let the system don`t scale the image and save some memory resources to scale it.

reference [Support different pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskUseDP)

Comment: When you say no need to choose, could you please elaborate. As suppose I want to design a new icon say example a `barcode rounded image` then I have to have a baseline with some size and then form ldpi,hdpi xhdpi and so on right?

Comment: It base on which design resolution of screen and physic size we have. 
For example, if we imaging our design size is base on FHD(1920x1080), 5.2" screen then the dpi is 424. As result, the density we choose is `xhdpi`.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `xxhdpi`.

Comment: Didn't quite get you, sorry. Could you please explain again. I want to target all resolutions of the screen sizes then what should I do?

Comment: Were you just asking how big is the icon`s size?

If you want to know how big is a proper icon. See https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#grid-keyline-shapes

And as definition system icon should be 24 x24 dp

Answer (score -1):

Check if this can help you,
[Material design icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline)